# Is it possible to Trim Wrapped Text at the bottom of the container in WPF?

Tags: wpf, word-wrap, texttrimming

I would like to trim the contents of a TextBlock at the bottom of the container when it runs out of space. The image below shows what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Example of desired effect]

The left cell contains text that is being wrapped at the end of the line, but is being cropped on the final line. The right cell (which I edited by hand) shows the effect I want to achieve by trimming the text on the last line.

Is there an (easy) way to achieve this in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the [TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx) property?

Comment: Yes I had, and it didn't work, but it turns out the text was inside a scrollviewer so it wasn't trimming. Moved the TextBlock into a grid and it works great. Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: There are no dumb questions, just dumb answers ;-)